# Can I use floppy drive pins on any motherboard as GPIO pins?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, raspberry-pi

Recently I saw some features of raspberry-pi, and the feature I was most attracted to was its GPIO (General Purpose Input Output) pins.
Then I wondered that I have an old motherboard that has floppy drive pins on it, then I plugged it in and started and installed ubuntu on it. It worked!

Now my question is:

1. **Can I use that floppy drive pins as GPIO pins?**
2. **If not, then please let me know which pins can be used as GPIO or there is nothing arrangement for that?**

Answer (score 1):

In general, the connections for the floppy disks are not usable as GPIO pins. If you have the exact specification of the chips that drive the floppy, than sometimes you might be able to do something with it, but it is by no means easy or guaranteed to work. So the answer is probably no.

Whether your motherboard has GPIO pins is impossible to know for us. Some Gigabyte motherboards seem to have them. Also, if your motherboard is so old that it has a parallel printer port, that would be a serious option.

The best option seems to use a GPIO-USB adapter if you want to control it directly. They should be available from around EUR 15 or equivalent in your local currency. Another option would be to look at Arduino. And, of course, a Pi zero W is also possible for that price.

Answer (score 0):

> old motherboard ... installed ubuntu

If Ubuntu is running out of the box, chances are the Floppy Controller is pretty "modern". Recent Ubuntu doesn't work that well on really old PCs.

> Can I use that floppy drive pins as GPIO pins?

You can use a few. Have a look at the [floppy connector](https://old.pinouts.ru/HD/InternalDisk_pinout.shtml), compare that with a datasheet, and you'll see that the only ones you can use easily are `Motor A Enable`, `Motor B Enable`, and `Drive Select`, as output pins.

And you may not even be able to use all of them; the Super-I/O chip on one of the older motherboards I have only supports a single drive (and hence single motor signal).

The rest is controlled by the complicated state machine which is the floppy controller. You may be able to trick the controller into using some of the other pins, by sending the right commands to it, but that requires a good knowledge about what is going on with the floppy signals.

So first, you need to find out the exact floppy controller (or Super-I/O chip) your motherboard has, and google for a manual or datasheet.

Second, Linux is not a real-time OS, so driving the pins when timing is critical is hard.

Third, modern Linux makes it increasingly painful to "just poke values to devices"; you may have to write a simple kernel driver.

If your old motherboard also has serial or parallel ports: It's much easier to use those as GPIO.

And, as written in the other answer, the simplest way is to spend a few EUR and buy a GPIO USB-device - then you won't have to fiddle with everything (but of course, fiddling has its own attractions).